# Skype for Business links didn´t start/open Skype for Business client

Tags: skype-for-business-2016

I have here a Skype for Business user, which gets some meeting links. But when the user click on the links the Skype for Business client isn´t opening. How can I solve that?

Update: On other PCs this is working fine for the affected user.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once Microsoft Skype for Business is installed on a computer, the local Microsoft Internet Explorer will become aware of special URLs used by the Microsoft Skype for Business environment. This is handled by the ActiveX plugin "MeetingJoinHelper Class" (e.g. LyncMeetingJoinAxOC.dll or MeetingJoinAxOC.dll). So if I where you I would check if the MeetingJoinHelper is running on the users PC in the IE options. If you need a more detailed you can find here a small [howto](http://www.admin-enclave.com/en/articles/skypeforbusiness/310-resolved-a-skype-for-business-user-isn%C2%B4t-able-to-join-meeting-via-invitation-link.html).